# Why does my wildcard search with SUMIF not work?

Tags: excel, text, contains, equality, sumifs

In MS Excel, I'm trying to make a wildcard search using the `SUMIF` function. I'm following [this guide](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/10/25/excel-if-cell-contains-count-sum/). However, for some reason my Excel doesn't think the words in the `range` are equal to the criterion.

Suppose I have the following data:
[image: The data in A2:B6]
I have `apple` as a criterion and want to find sum all the cells adjacent to one containing the word apple.  My formula is:
`=sumif(A2:A6, "*apple*", B2:B6)`

Now, for some reason the result of the sum function amounts to nothing.

I also tried another test, which I think my error has to do with. If I type `= "apple" = "*apple*", Excel returns` False`. The two are related, I think, but I don't see how I can solve my original problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=sumif(b2:b6,"*apple*",a2:a6)
```

As according to your example you have the sum range first followed by the range you are controlling against.

That is the wrong way round for sumif().

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your help! 
However, I put it wrongly in my original request, but not in my Excel. My Excel formula's arguments were correct, but still it didn't work for some reason. 
I found the error: where my numbers were formatted with comma's as decimal mark, instead of dots. This made the formula add to zero. 
Thanks again for your help!